# It's over... Jon Skeet has 1008K rep and 7 bronze badges

Tags: feature-request

Jon Skeet hit 1M total rep network wide.

[image]

And apparently has 7 bronze badges.

Something has to be done.

Comment: Maybe that something can be something more concrete

Comment: [SOMETHING MUST BE DONE!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism) I say, we all take a drink.

Comment: OK... whose job is it to turn on the "m" button in the small text? Alternately or in addition, turn on "k" for the badges... also, someone needs to tell Jon to work on his referral numbers... it's appalling.

Comment: What do you propose should be done?

Comment: @SirPython Give me his rep.

Comment: Wait a minute.... http://imgur.com/RF7IQge

Comment: @RikerW *total network-wide rep* ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug that is his area 51 rep though... THAT STILL COUNTS

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with [meta-tag:bug]? *the stack overflowed*

Comment: I shouldn't have given him so much bounties :(

Answer (score 6):

> ## It's over… Something has to be done.

It's not over. *You* can compare yourself to the guy who started almost a decade ago - but no one else will.

We are fighting a neverending battle against ignorance, unanswered questions, spammers, and sign-offs.

So get back out there, write good questions and good answers, and if you can't shoot, you can carry bullets - so go fix spelling errors, typos, grammar problems, and flag bad content. In one way or another, we reward all of these efforts, and they won't be overshadowed or eclipsed by anyone else. The honors, the badges and points, you earn, they are yours, and no one can take them away. Except Shog if you misbehave.

Comment: _if you can't shoot, you can carry bullets_  <-- Golden!

Answer (score 2):

Bronze is much to low a valuation for Jon Skeet.  He only considers gold medals to have any value.

Side note the silver ones are a bug in the system, we should fix that..